# Need for mongo-java-driver with Spring-data-MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am new to mongoDB and Spring so want some clarification.

I went through many tutorials some just use

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

while others use :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>
```

So what is the use of *mongo-java-driver*? and why is it required if we can connect to mongoDB without it?

Answer (score -1):

You only combine them when

1. You are using Spring Data Framework (otherwise, you'd only need the Mongo driver)
2. You want to use a Mongo Driver other than 2.13.0, which is included already (referring to your first POM)

See [**Compile dependencies**](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent/1.7.2.RELEASE)

By the way `1.7.2.RELEASE` was released 2015, so best go upgrade

Comment: But in my pom, mongo-java-driver version is 2.11.0. Is that wrong according to your 2nd point ?

Comment: See the link. 2.13.0, the later version is will be used instead